# SSD_MOBILENET V1 to TensorRT in Tensorflow 1.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, models, object-detection, tensorrt

Folks,

I have a Jetson TX2 with tensorflow 1.6 and jetpack 3.2 (tensorrt 3.0) installed. I installed UFF as well. 
How can I convert the ssd_mobilenet_v1 frozen graph from tensorflow into tensorRT equivalent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Visit the github repo: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tf_to_trt_image_classification
Follow the instructions, it should help you out.
You should convert the frozen graphs to a plan(TensorRT Engine equivalient) and then serialize it, while performing inference you deserialise the TensorRT engine and perform inference.